# Error with picker view swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uipickerview

I'm trying to change text font and color of picker view. But when i do that i get an error, please help.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "some string", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red])
    return attributedString
}
```

[image: ErrorImage]

Answer (score 0):

i did something like that by providing a view like this

```
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
          let pickerLabel = UILabel()
          pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
          pickerLabel.text = "\(dataSource[row])"

          pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Light", size: 70)
          pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
          return pickerLabel
       }

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
      return 1
   }

   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
      return dataSource.count
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the methods that the `UIPickerViewDataSource` wants you to implement. These include:

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
```

and

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
```

ex:

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}
```